# Telerik Label control for Silverlight - no Click event?

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I am looking to handle the click event on a Telerik Label control in a Silverlight application, but cannot find a click event attribute setting. DoubleClick is catered for (it appears in Intellisense), but not Click. Surely I am missing something obvious here, but I cannot find it.

I tried adding a Click event handler using Caliburn Micro, but that isn't firing either. It's as though the Telerik Label control stubbornly doesn't want to respond to being (single) clicked.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean `Click` like `Button.Click` or do you mean `MouseLeftButtonDown`?

Comment: Mouse left button down might do. I want to toggle a checkbox with every click on the label, the way the content of a checkbox works. I can't use the checkbox content for whatever reason, but I want to preserve the expected behavior - that left clicking the text next to the checkbox toggles the value.